# How to change permission to files in Dockerfile when running in OpenShift

Tags: docker, openshift

As I have discovered, OpenShift runs all containers as non-root, so if I have to write to a file inside a container, I get an `Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'database.db~'`. This is my  Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:9-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
COPY database.db .

RUN chmod 666 database.db <-- This doesn't work
RUN npm install

COPY index.js .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD npm start
```

But `chmod` doesn't seem to work. I don't know why.

Comment: Did you try to set the mode on the **host**?

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: @Maroun Okay, I think I get what you mean. Changing the file permissions in my machine before building the Docker image, doesn't work... :(

Comment: Have a look at [these guidelines](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/openshift_images/create-images.html#images-create-guide-openshift_create-images) for details on how to create container images supporting arbitrary user IDs. If the used `alpine` base image is not a must, you may want to [use one of the existing Node.js builder images](https://learn.openshift.com/middleware/rhoar-getting-started-nodejs/) that are likely available in the cluster and just provide your source code.

Comment: I will read the guidelines, thanks. The alpine image is mandatory due to requirements of the project